# Phalcon Config File Dynamic Template

Tags: php, templates, phalcon

```
'application' => array(
    'controllersDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../app/controllers/',
    'modelsDir'      => __DIR__ . '/../../app/models/',
    'viewsDir'       => __DIR__ . '/../../app/views/templates/$dynamic_template_folder',
    'pluginsDir'     => __DIR__ . '/../../app/plugins/',
    'libraryDir'     => __DIR__ . '/../../app/library/',
    'cacheDir'       => __DIR__ . '/../../app/cache/',
    'baseUri'        => '/phalcon_project/',
 )
```

how can i get $dynamic_template_folder from database in config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's rather an odd question. Normally your config is defined before you do any logic, so the only way of doing that in the config file is to open a connection to your database, get the value and append it to the `/../../app/views/templates/`.

A much better way of doing that would be in you DI, when you define you view service. Also consider caching the database calls or storing the data in a session if possible to avoid unnecessary calls.

```
$di->setShared('view', function () use ($di, $configuration) {
    $templateDir = $di->db->…; // Load the necessary details from the db.

    $view = new View();
    $view->setViewsDir($configuration->viewsDir . $templateDir);
    $view->registerEngines([…]);
    return $view;
});
```